# bought a token that is unsellable, but I do not spot the code in the contrat that is responsible

Tags: solidity, erc-20, contract-design, contract-debugging, scam

I bought this token, had a good app for trading and a well written medium which didn't seem scammish at all.

the token even managed to pass on the normal basic tools for honeypot detection and tokensniffer (which after a 100 score is now retracted and pending review).

token is unsellable, when i tried skipping uniswaps app and using the V2 router contract directly, the error somehow relates to gas.I confirmed this when i tried to move some of the tokens to a different wallet and it failed and gave a "out of gas" error.

I have looked over the contract, and cannot see where the problem is. The team are able to sell the token, and so did someone else who I am guessing is part of the scam. if anyone could help explain where in the contract is the code causing the issue, I'd be eternally grateful. I am guessing there isn't a workaround to get the funds out, but I would at least like to be able to spot this code from now on.

here is the contract for "RUPX"
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf59f55a77bcf64bfe4f9d3ad82b67838fea98ad3

thanks in advance for reading and your help!

Answer (score 2):

After reading the code I found that the `_transfer` is overridden:

```
function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        if (amount == 0) {
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }

        if (limitsInEffect) {
            if (
                from != owner() &&
                to != owner() &&
                to != address(0) &&
                to != address(0xdead) &&
                !swapping
            ) {
```

Based on my code review, as you can see you have a condition here where if you're not the owner, you're subject to everything inside the condition. This will be ignored if you're the owner. I didn't share the whole function because it is too long.

So this includes a condition where non-owners will be affected by the code inside it, but owners will not.

Comment: thanks for looking at this. is there a workaround? is there nothing that can be done? I see a few other wallets that are not the owner that are able to sell.

Comment: try to sell small amounts, are you sure that the transactions are failing ? can you show me any submitted failed transaction ?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x86735c123bea59a9cc793d95bb4e8140bd647e187fdfffefc5adf585deff26d0

for example here I tried to send to an alternate wallet in case it was blacklisting wallets that had purchased, and the transfer to a wallet failed.

I've tried to sell small amounts and it still gives a warning that the swap will fail, citing that it cannot estimate the correct amount of gas needed.